# Tag system - Search by tag at click Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I want to make a search function by tags. When a tag is clicked, to show me all the content with the value from tag ( like model, tag1, tag2 etc. ). For that, I make a page and tested if this can displays what I need. With `->where('tag', '=', 'model')` I got all posts with `tag = model'. But now, I need to display based on what tag is clicked.
So, here is what I have in single-news : [image]

**These tags are generated by this code:**

```
<div class="container">
            <label>Tags

              <a href="{{ url('') }}">
                  <input class="input-tags" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" value="{{ $news->tag }}" disabled>
              </a>


              </label>
            </div>

        </div>
```

**Here is my controller at the moment:**

```
public function newsTag()
        {

                $data = $this->data;



                $data['news_details'] = News::with('category_name')->where('locale','=',Session::get('locale'))->where('tag','=','model')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();


                $data['categories'] = Category::with(['news' => function ($q){
                        $q->orderBy('title', 'asc');}])->where('category','=','news')->where('locale','=',Session::get('locale'))->get();

                // $data['categories'] = Category::with('news')->where('category','=','news')->where('locale','=',Session::get('locale'))->get();

                $data['instanews_details'] = InstagramNews::where('locale','=',Session::get('locale'))->where('category','=','news')->get();

                // $displayitem = DisplayItem::where('slug','=',url('project'))->first();

                // $data['page'] = $displayitem;
                // date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
                // // return $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                // return $date = strtotime('-1 hour');
                // echo 'John visited last ' . $date;

                $data['title'] = trans('fab.news');;

                $data['breadcrumb'] = 'news';

                // $data['menu'] = $tag->title;

                $data['metadescription'] = "news";

                $data['metatitle'] = 'news';

                // $data['blogs'] = $tag->blog;

                return view('news.news_tag',$data);

        }
```

**Here is my route:**

```
Route::get('news_tag', 'ModelController@newsTag');
```

**Here is my page for results - news_tag.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layout.front.template')
@section('content')

<!-- Profile talent section -->
   <section class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid modificartion" style="overflow: hidden;">
   <div class="container news-container">
      <div id="news-rows" class="row">
          <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12">
              <div class="vc_column-inner ">
                  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                     <section class="gallery-element isotop padding-item none-padding hidden-s hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                        <div class="container">
                           <div class="header-element">
                               <h3 id="newstxt" class="title-element font-disolve">@lang('fab.news')</h3>
                           </div>
                           <div class="content-tab">
                               <div id="options" class="clearfix">
                                  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                   <ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix inline-mainb" data-option-key="filter" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                                      @lang('fab.newsletter')
                                   </ul>
                                 </a>
                               </div>

                               <div class="row" style="margin-right:0px;bottom: 40px; position: relative">

                                 <div class="col-md-3 contentWrap" id="column1" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                                   <ul class="scroller3 content">
                                     @foreach($news_details as $key => $news)
                                         <!-- <ul class="scroller1"> -->


                                             <a href="{{ url('news') }}/{{ $news->slug }}">
                                               <div class="element transition {{ $news->category_name->slug }} editorial news video-exhibition" style="width: 100%">
                                                 <div class="item-gallery {{ $news->news_class }}">
                                                   <div class="content-item">
                                                       <img src="{{ url('images/news') }}/{{ $news->image }}"/>
                                                      <div class="text">
                                                          <div class="name">{{ $news->category_name->title }}</div>
                                                          <div class="content-gallery-grid">
                                                             <h3 class="title">
                                                               <!-- <a href="{{ url('news') }}/{{ $news->slug }}"> -->
                                                                 {{ $news->title }}
                                                               <!-- </a> -->
                                                             </h3>
                                                          </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                 </div>
                                              </div>
                                             </a>


                                     @endforeach
                                   </ul>
                                 </div><!-- 1st col -->
                               </div>

@stop
```

So, to conclude, I need to make this search function based of the tags from single news of every news. 
So, If news with id 1 has `tags - test, tag, me, phone`, and I press on `tag`, I want to be redirected to news_tag page, and to get only posts with `tag` on column `tag` from table `News`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your question!

Would it be possible to alter the structure of your code so that it supports a many-to-many relation on News to Tags?

From what I can see from your app, News can have many Tags, and a Tag can have many News items.

Below is a package I frequently use for tagging from the developers at Spatie:

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-tags

The examples at the link there show how you could add tags to your News items (or for any other table in your app).

Does that help with what you're trying to achieve?